# JPA: data table after insert doesnt show the @joincolumn @ManyToOne

Tags: java, jpa, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying a web project using JPA and JSF-primefaces.
I have a bug with insert/update an object which has @ManyToOne relationship.

after inserting, @JoinColumn is blank field. (sorry ican't post image, this is image link)

[after insert](http://postimg.org/image/4x8hcd7fr/)

and then, after reload list, blank field is back to normal

[after reload](http://postimg.org/image/rxf4op59j/)

I'm using unidirectional @ManyToOne entity

Place.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "place")
@XmlRootElement

public class Place implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Basic(optional = false)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Integer id;
   ...
   @Basic(optional = false)
   @NotNull
   @Column(name = "prefecture_id")
   private int prefectureId;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "prefecture_id",referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false,insertable = false)
   private Aken prefecture;
```

Aken.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "aken")
@XmlRootElement
public class Aken implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Short id;
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "data")
    private String data;
```

method update to database

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class PlaceFacade extends AbstractFacade<Place> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "JutenPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction userTransaction;

    public void edit(Place place){
      try{
          getUserTransaction().begin();
          getEntityManager().merge(place);
          getUserTransaction().commit();
          }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          }
      }
```

method retrieve data on table

```
public List<Place> findAll() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq =   getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(Place.class));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

I'm using JAVA EE7, glassfish server 4, primefaces 4.0

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
@JoinColumn(name = "prefecture_id",referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false,insertable = false)
```

you marked Place foreign key column READONLY.

remove limitations: `@JoinColumn(name = "prefecture_id",referencedColumnName = "id")`